# Uploadcare widget with multi-file uploads limited with max size

Tags: angular, file-upload, uploadcare

I have an Uploadcare widget with multi-file uploads.

```js
<ngx-uploadcare-widget #uploadCare 
  images-only="true"
  multiple="isMultiple"
  multiple-min="0"
  multiple-max="10
  data-max-size="21048576"
  data-clearable="true" 
  public-key="****"
  (on-change)="onFileUploadChange($event)">
```

1. I want the uploaded files size to not exceed 2 MB. How do I set `max-size` for the all uploaded files?
2. How can I prevent duplication for uploading files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There's no such an option out of the box, but you can achieve this with [file validation](https://uploadcare.com/docs/file_uploads/widget/moderation/). Check out an example in the demo app [here](https://github.com/uploadcare/ngx-uploadcare-widget/blob/master/demo/app/app.component.ts#L50.). A validation function has access to file information before it's completely uploaded and allows you to validate the file size, name, mime-type, image dimensions, etc. If the file doesn't pass the validation, you can abort uploading and throw a custom error.
2. Checking for file duplicated is not supported by Uploadcare.